# Bugsnag: Error uploading source mappings?

Tags: android, react-native, bugsnag

I am trying to upload source mappings to Bugsnag so I can view the full stack trace when an error occurs, rather than the stack trace of the bundled file. I followed the instructions on [this](https://docs.bugsnag.com/build-integrations/gradle/) page but I got this error when trying to build an APK:

```
> Task :app:uploadBugsnagReleaseMapping
Mapping file not found: null
```

I looked at my `android\app\build.gradle` file and noticed that the `minifiedEnabled` property was set to false. I changed it to true and then the error changed to:

```
Mapping file not found: C:\Development\React Native Practise\bugsnag_practise\android\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt
```

I thought I needed to add the file manually so I added an empty text file with that name, in that directory and got this:

```
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
Retrying Bugsnag upload (1/5) ...
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
Retrying Bugsnag upload (2/5) ...
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
Retrying Bugsnag upload (3/5) ...
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
Retrying Bugsnag upload (4/5) ...
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
Retrying Bugsnag upload (5/5) ...
Attempting upload of mapping file to Bugsnag
Bugsnag upload failed with code 422: Received empty file
```

If it helps, this is my bugsnag configuration within `android\app\build.gradle`:

```
bugsnag {
    autoUpload true
    ndk false
    autoReportBuilds true
    autoProguardConfig true
    overwrite true
    retryCount 5
}
```

and my buildTypes config in the same file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

Is there a config option missing that will populate this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable obfuscation in `app/proguard-rules.pro`

```
# Disabling obfuscation is useful if you collect stack traces from production crashes
# (unless you are using a system that supports de-obfuscate the stack traces).
# Disable to generate mapping.txt Enable for production apk
-dontobfuscate <- Comment this line
```

And try again

Comment: I marked this as correct as this, along with `-printmapping obfuscate/mapping.txt` meant the file was created and populated with data.

Comment: I keep getting the same error when I comment that line out. I also tried adding '-printmapping obfuscate/mapping.txt' but still, same error.